# Sitecore Commerce 9.3 Catalog items and Product not added after installation

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sxa-storefront

I have installed Sitecore Commerce 9.3 recently. I am not able to find any catalog items (Habitat_Master) under the storefront settings.

This results of giving some errors in Storefront site accessing sxa.storefront.com.

And all the other products buckets and catagories are empty. I am also getting an error 'Habitat_Master' is already associated with another item when choosing Habitat_Master in catalog configuration.

Please suggest me solution for this issue.

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-commerce/clean-and-initialize-the-environment.html
Try this suggested by Sitecore support.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your catalog is not selected in path - **/sitecore/Commerce/Catalog Management/Catalogs**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution suggested over here: https://andrewsutherland.azurewebsites.net/tag/storefront/

**Solution:**

Removing the lock can be achieved by executing the following script against the commerce shared database.

Update the database name and catalog friendly id values, in the highlighted lines, as appropriate.

```
USE SitecoreCommerce9_SharedEnvironments
GO
 
DECLARE @catalogEntityId VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Habitat_Master';
DECLARE @uniqueId VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @entity VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @modifiedEntity VARCHAR(MAX);
 
SELECT @entity = Entity,
       @uniqueId = Entities.UniqueId
FROM   sitecore_commerce_storage.CatalogEntities AS Entities
       INNER JOIN sitecore_commerce_storage.CatalogEntity AS Entity
               ON Entities.UniqueId = Entity.UniqueId
WHERE  Id = 'Entity-Catalog-' + @catalogEntityId
 
UPDATE sitecore_commerce_storage.CatalogEntity
SET    Entity = JSON_MODIFY(@entity, '$.ParentCatalogList', '')
WHERE  UniqueId = @uniqueId
```

Now that we have released the lock, we can associate the catalog to our site.

It worked for me for similar kind of issue.